# Using bootstrap in Ruby on rails Error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap for my RubyonRails application and I am not able to set it up.

In my Gemfile I added

```
#Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.5'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

I did `bundle install` after that

I created a application.css.scss in the app/assets/stylesheets folder and the contents are:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap"
```

> app/assets/javascripts/application.js :

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

When I run the rails server and go to my root page, I get the following error:

```
couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css'
```

Comment: can you check to see what version of 'sprockets' you have? Run
bundle list | grep sprockets

Comment: @nzajt sprockets (3.3.4)
  * sprockets-rails (2.3.3)

Comment: that isn't the issue. From the github page "Please make sure sprockets-rails is at least v2.1.4." and you do.

Comment: Sorry, I think that issue is that you need the application.css to be application.scss

Comment: Right now it is application.css.scss. Should there be css?

Comment: I just added my answer it should be application.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your application.css and turn it into application.scss. There should not be any thing above this in your file. Remove all the old code above. It should just be.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

If you want to add another file you just add it below. like

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "ANOTHER SCSS FILE";
```

Comment: Thanks its working now :) Will I need to include anything in my application.html.erb file? Are all the bootstrap fonts/javascript files loaded?

Comment: You should be good. As long as you keep the name application.scss you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, the only thing that helping was including the older version of the SASS gem

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

**Use SCSS for stylesheets**

**gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'**

Comment: Had the same issue , after spending an hour on the stackoverflow/github, found that the only solution was to:                                                                add the gem 'saas-rails' '>3.2'                                                                            and comment out the gem 'sass-rails''~5.0'

Comment: i had the same issue :couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'
The only solution was to comment off 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' and add instead 
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

in the Gemfile, hope this helps other members